# IF condition with a string

Tags: c#, .net, windows, string, if-statement

Just a quick one:

```
string firstline; 
if (firstline == null) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("String empty!");
}
```

In theory if there is no value in "firstline", the console should out put "String empty!"?

Comment: Is this correct, since I am getting no output..

Comment: yes, it passes the null check because firstline variable is defined but not instantiated yet

Comment: "Use of unassigned variable" ...

Comment: Perhaps show us code that actually compiles.

Comment: So have your problem been solved? Any questions? Please confirm one of the following answers.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't even compile because of:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'firstline'

When you say you don't get any output but the program compiles and runs just fine, you are not showing us your real code.

---

However, if `firstline` is not a local variable but a member variable of the surrounding class, it will be automatically initialized with `null`. In general, all member variables of a class are initialized with `default(T)` where `T` is the type of the member variable.

Comment: It would if the actual code "would" use it to access object of unassigned variable. But in this case he is only checking instance.

Comment: @Igoris: I don't understand your comment. The usage of an unassigned local variable is always false.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth sorry crap example, it was declared as public, I just added the string in quickly

Comment: as i said "usage" of variable would throw runtime error (or compile if it is not by reference). What do you mean by "The usage of an unassigned local variable is always false". If you USE variable which is not instantiated, it would throw NullReferenceException.

Comment: "The usage of an unassigned local variable is always false" <- Sorry, this comment was nonsense. I was reading something else while typing it :-) It should read "The usage of an unassigned local variable is always invalid". However, you are mixing unassigned local variables and variables that have been assigned with null! You will never get a `NullReferenceException` from using an unassigned local variable, because such code doesn't even compile. Example: `Stream s; s.Close(); // Doesn't compile` as opposed to `Stream s = null; s.Close(); // Throws NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 1):

You can't compile in VS with error: Use of unassigned local variable 'firstline'    !

Try assign null before!

**EDIT**

or

```
class Program
{
    static string firstline; # with static you can compile and got your behaviour

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        if (firstline == null)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("String empty!");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In default they are not null. If you want it null by default use this:

```
static string firstline;
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    if (firstline == null)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("String empty!");
    }
}
```

But I suggest using this one:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string firstline = null;
    // or this:
    //string firstline = String.Empty;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstline))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("String empty!");
    }
}
```

In both ways you can get riddle of

> Use of unassigned local variable 'firstline'

Answer (score 0):

Yes that will behave as you expect and should print out to the console. You might find that the console application closes too quickly for you to read the result though if you've not got any following code.

Also null and "" (or String.Empty) often mean the same thing, so a more command way to do this is:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstline))
{
   Console.WriteLine("String is empty!");
}
```

Comment: Hmm strange, I seem to remember a value e.g. == NullOrEmpty, can't remember exactly what it was tough

Comment: -1: Not correct. It doesn't even compile. `string firstline;` is **NOT** equivalent to `string firstline = null;` as the first is invalid and the second is valid.

Comment: Changed downvote to upvote - he was talking about a member variable and I assume you were too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct, Use of unassigned local variable 'firstline'. You can assign it with any value to test. If you want to check if it is an empty string, a better way is:

```
string firstline = null;  //change to "" to test
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstline))
{
  System.Console.WriteLine("String empty!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology makes it sound like you are a little confused.

A `null` string is precisely that - the absence of the value. It is not an empty string, it is a string with no value.

An empty string is a zero length string, `""` or `string.Empty`. This is not `null` as it does have a value, but the value is zero length.

Often you want to treat the null and empty values the same, in which case you might use the check

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstline))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("String is null or empty!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here are my 2 cents:

```
 if (firstline == (string)null) throw new ArgumentNullException("firstline"); //value is null
 if (firstline.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("firstline", "Value is empty"); // string.Empty
```

I found this by using [Pex and Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)